# onclick an <li> to open local redirect

Tags: javascript, html

Hello i am just building a website for a FiveM Server. It has an button on it which is actually an `li` element and if you click it FiveM should locally open and connect to the Server with this Link `fivem://connect/nextroleplay.de:30120`. This works.

Because of that the Button is an li element i tried following with onclick

```html
                   <li class="nav-link playnow" onclick="location.href='fivem://connect/nextroleplay.de:30120">
                        <a href="#">
                            <i class='bx bx-play icon' ></i>
                            <span class="text nav-text">JETZT SPIELEN</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
```

But NOTHING happens. Why?

The "Button" looks like this:

[Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1iv4Y.png)

[Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5OnZ.png)

Comment: Open your developer console and see what happens when the click is occuring.

Comment: JavaScript will prevent navigation like that, because the `fivem://` protocol isn't known to it, it must be registered. Instead, why not just use `<a href="fivem://yoururl"></a>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing quote check below

```
 <li class="nav-link playnow" onclick="location.href='fivem://connect/nextroleplay.de:30120'">
                        <a href="#">
                            <i class='bx bx-play icon' ></i>
                            <span class="text nav-text">JETZT SPIELEN</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
```

Comment: Yeah, but you will still get the `Prevented navigation to “fivem://connect/nextroleplay.de:30120” due to an unknown protocol.` error.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Javascript function and then use that function in "onclick" event like below. Check this once.

```js
function navigate() {
    location.href = "fivem://connect/nextroleplay.de:30120";
}
```

```html
<li class="nav-link playnow" onclick="navigate()">
        <a href="#">
            <i class=' bx bx-play icon'></i>
            <span class="text nav-text">JETZT SPIELEN</span>
        </a>
    </li>
```

Comment: Looks like that would still give the same error of `Prevented navigation to “fivem://connect/nextroleplay.de:30120” due to an unknown protocol.`

Comment: You also don't necessarily need to wrap it in a function like this, OP was missing the closing quote, but other than that his solution wasn't incorrect.

Comment: I added the closing quote and checked in vs code, I still got error. So I went in this function method. Thanks for your feedback

Comment: if you still face error create hidden link and run in javascript function document.getElementById('fivem').click()